# Limite de upload com php.ini no Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Por favor, você sabe como alterar a Configuração

```
PHP > no Cpanel > software/serviços > 
    > File Uploads  upload_max_filesize Maximum allowed size for uploaded files
```

de 2M para 10M (por exemplo)?

Lembando que já tentei todas as formas indicadas: via htaccess, php.ini, upinfo.php. Pedi uma ajuda para a Locaweb, mas me botaram para trovar com um agente online (máquina) mais desinformado que eu.

Estou com um arquivo xml para subir, que é barrado por esta configuração.

Answer (score 3):

Suponho que voce tenha uma hospedagem php e com acesso cpanel a ela, o primeiro que eu tentaria seria colocar um arquivo php.ini em /public_html com o seguinte conteudo:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
;upload_tmp_dir =

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 128M
```

Ou então coloque seu php.ini pra gente dar uma olhada.

Comment: Melkysalem, como já havia aplicado antes, via php.ini não funcionou, mas de qualquer forma muitíssimo obrigado pela resposta de pronto. Vou solicitar ao pessoal da Locaweb a alteração. Abs

Comment: Melkysalem, finalmente encontrei o a solução, o arquivo php.ini deve ir para a pasta wp-admim, em se tratando de wordpress. RESOLVIDO! Abs.

Comment: Que bom, já fica resolvido pros próximos que precisarem, abs

Comment: Pedro poste a solução como resposta e não como comentário e aceite!

Comment: Cara, valeu demais pela resposta, estou apanhando a mais de hora aqui, criei php.ini mas tinha colocado ele na raiz, e não no wp-admin. Salvou a pátria aqui!

Answer (score 1):

Vá até o seu **wp-config.php** e adicione a linha abaixo

```
ini_set("upload_max_filesize","128M"); // essa linha serve para alterar o valor do upload_max_filesize.
```

Answer (score 0):

Para quem está passando pelo mesmo problema, segue a dica de [**Pedro**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/13503/pedro) que comentou a resposta.

Se você tentou colocar o arquivo `php.ini` na raiz, ou na pasta `/public_html` e ainda assim não funcionou e você usa o servidor da **Locaweb**.

Para tentar alterar os valores de de upload, crie o arquivo `php.ini` dentro da pasta `wp-admin` do WordPress (Comigo funcionou).

Geralmente há um arquivo `php.ini` modelo na raiz do usuário no caso da **Locaweb**, copie o conteúdo dele e coloque dentro da pasta indicada e altere as linhas seguintes:

`upload_max_filesize = 50M
post_max_size = 50M`

O número **50M** pode ser o de sua necessidade. Se seu problema foi outro e conseguiu resolver, poste e deixe a comunidade saber.

Answer (score -1):

Basta somente acrescentar essa linha:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 256M
```

No final do arquivo `.htaccess`

Answer (score -2):

Basta somente acrescentar essa linha:

php_value upload_max_filesize 256M
No final do arquivo .htaccess

lembrando que é M ao invés de MB ou K ao invés de KB!